# jBPM 7.0 start event at fix time every day

Tags: events, jbpm

I have been working with jBPM and the KIE Workbench for a short time. I want to create a business process, which is started automatically every day at a fixed time. How do I configure the start timer event?

Example: Start every day at 1:00 pm local time.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try using timer start event to start process instance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the start timer event in your process definition and use a cron based scheduling. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-bpmn2/src/test/resources/BPMN2-TimerStartCron.bpmn2). 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. 

@Akjun Teh:
I don't understand where i can set the fix time. I need a timer which is start every day at the same and at a fix time.

Comment: Here is where you include your time cycle.                                
`<timerEventDefinition>
        <timeCycle xsi:type="tFormalExpression" language="cron">
        R/PT1D
        </timeCycle>
 </timerEventDefinition>`

You can read up abit here to better understand how the timer work. https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.2/userguide/jBPMBPMN2.html#d0e3888

Comment: Please accept the answer if you have solve the question to help others get to the answer as well. Thanks